# Nginx no longer starts and doesn't give output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, deployment, nginx, unicorn

I was using nginx for a uniq app, then I changed it and configured for server blocks (AKA Vhost-in apache), following the steps this tuto shows
[(see the tutorial)](https://github.com/Hack56/Rails-Template/wiki/Running-Multiple-Rails-Apps-on-Nginx)

The server worked (just with *service gninx restart*) till I reboot the VPS

**NOW NGINX ISNT STARTING AND NO OUTPUT MSG is being shown** 
(tried all the start ways)

What am I missing?

`$ /etc/init.d/nginx status` **returns:**

```
 * nginx is not running
```

**Diggin from my local machine returns**

```
$ dig http://www.xx.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> http://www.xx.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

(added on edit) - - - - - - - --  - - -
For my other domain

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> http://www.xx.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 5145
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;http://www.xx.com  IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
xx.com .    900 IN  SOA

;; Query time: 39 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun  4 21:01:55 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 110
```

**When curl:**

```
curl http://www.xx.com -v
* About to connect() to www.xx.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 198.199.199.155... Conexão recusada*
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

**(refused connection)*

**ping results:**
`33 packets transmitted, 33 received, 0% packet loss, time 197754ms`

---

**My config:**

I've added my domains to **/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost xx
198.199.199.155 www.xx.com
198.199.199.155 xx.com
198.199.199.155 www.yy.com
198.199.199.155 yy.com
```

On my **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes 1;
user nobody nogroup;
pid /tmp/nginx.pid;
error_log /tmp/nginx.error.log;
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
  accept_mutex off;
}
http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log /tmp/nginx.access.log combined;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay off;
  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_min_length 500;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css
             text/comma-separated-values
             text/javascript application/x-javascript
             application/atom+xml;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
  ##########################################################
  # Catch all requests to server ip so just hitting the ip
  # won't render anything.
  ##########################################################
 server {
    listen   80 default;
    server_name  anything;
         # Everything is a 404
    location / {
        return 404;
    }
  }
}
```

- EDITED -

*ps: IP and domains are fakes -.-'*

Comment: tail the nginx error log and the do a `sudo service nginx start` , paste the error that appears from starting nginx

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a problem here:

```
#server {
    listen   80 default;
    server_name  anything;
    # Everything is a 404
    location / {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

`server` is commented out, but the other lines in that set are not.

If you intended on commenting out the entire `server` block, you'll need to use:

```
#server {
#    listen   80 default;
#    server_name  anything;
#    # Everything is a 404
#    location / {
#        return 404;
#    }
#}
```

Comment: just a mistake I ve made when pasted the code here. TY anyway dude.

BTW, more info: also commented or not the behaviour still is the same.